# Do I need to install R on a server to run a project that uses renv?

Tags: r, rscript, renv

Lets just say I created an R project using renv on server1, where R installed.

Then I need to move the whole project to a server2, where R is NOT installed.

So because I am using renv in my project, do I still need to install R on server2?
Or I can simply use renv and run project on server2?

Thanks

Comment: I think `renv` only deals with packages, not with R itself. E.g. under *caveats* on [their site](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html): _"R version: `renv` tracks, but doesn’t help with, the version of R used with the packge. `renv` can’t easily help with this because it’s run inside of R, but you might find tools like `rig` helpful, as they make it easier to switch between multiple version of R on one computer."_

Comment: Lets say you didnt use renv at all, and have a project built on R on server 1, and you move to server 2 that doesnt have R, how do you expect to run your project on server 2 without R , what is going to interpret and execute the R project you built if not for ..R ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you want to run {renv} you need to install R exactutables. It's an R package. It helps handling with the version of other R packages, but not with the version of the R executables If you don't want to use Docker or R binaries of your S.O., I could recommend you to use rig (The R Installation Manager).